# How to change fontFamily of a button text through layout XML file in android?

Tags: android, button

The title pretty much describes my question. I want to change the font of the text written on my button using XML files. Is it possible? For a simple TextView, this works:

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
```

But for buttons, how can we do it by using **only the layout xml files**?

Comment: The same property works for `Button` as well

Comment: My bad. I couldn't observe the change in font and thought `android:fontFamily` wasn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Android comes with 3 fonts `(Sans, Serif, Monospace)` which can be accesed using `android:typeface=”FONT_NAME”`. For using your own fonts, read [this](http://russenreaktor.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/solved-android-using-custom-fonts/) article. May it will help.

Programmatically

```
Button n=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Helv Neue 67 Med Cond.ttf");
      n.setText("show");
      n.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use this:

```
android:typeface=”FONT_NAME”
```

Hope it helps.